# MYSQL Хранение url изображение продукта

Tags: mysql, img

**Как лучше хранить ссылку на изображение продукта в базе данных магазина?**

таблица для хранения товаров - *goods*:

```
id | name | country | price | avaliable | season
```

Теперь озадачился вопросом хранения `url` на изображение товара, первая мысль добавить столбцы

```
 | img | thm
```

В столбце `img` хранить ссылку на исходное изображение, а в `thm` ссылку на превью изображения.

**Но как быть когда товар имеет более одного изображения?**

Варианты которые пришли в голову:

1. хранить массивы в этих столбцах  `| img | thm | массивы`
2. создать отдельную таблицу - *goodimage*:

   ```
   id | good_ref_id | img | thm |
   ```

   где `good_ref_id = id` товара в таблице `goods`

Comment: да, лучше отдельную таблицу. Если в списках товаров картинки так же показываются И будет подтормаживать выборка для них, можно одну, главную, картинку продублировать в основной таблице. правда `thm` я  бы не делал, путь к ней можно вычислять по пути к большой картинке. thm например с теми же именами но в другой папке. При желании можно вообще не хранить пути. А только кол-во картинок а путь полностью вычислять по id товара и номеру картинки ../images/good-id.num.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишу и свой ответ тоже.
По сути он совпадает и с ответами @Mike и @Blacknife: *картинки лучше хранить в отдельной таблице*.
Но в защиту приведу несколько тезисов, с которыми столкнулся.

1. Даже если в товаре одна картинка, нет гарантий, что заказчик через полгода не придет и не предоставит еще фотографии товара. В таком случае Вам не придется ничего кардинально ни в коде, ни в базе менять.
2. Для каждой картинки в таблице лучше хранить имя файла. Имена файлов остальных размеров можно вычислить.
   Например, имя файла `1234.jpg` хранится в базе. Тогда остальные размеры (превью: `1234_thumb.jpg`, супер качество: `1234_hires.jpg` и т.д.) можно вычислять в PHP. А заодно и проверять наличие.
3. При загрузке новой картинки вместо старой (замена), имена файлов лучше менять. Так Вам не придется иметь дело с кэшированием браузерами. Все Ваши посетители (и новые, и возвратники) увидят новую картинку сразу же.
4. Имея картинки в отдельной таблице у Вас появляется возможность указавать их свойства/аттрибуты... ну как угодно. Например:

   - можно добавить колонку `order`, тогда Вы можете определять их порядок отображения в карточке товара
   - можно добавить колонку `imagePriority`, и в ней указывать, какая из картинок главная, какая второстепенная. Правда этого же можно достигнуть и с колонкой `order`
   - в этой же таблице можно хранить и видео (если к товару прилагается). Причем можно даже ссылку на YouTube, например. А для облегчения выборки товаров, у которых есть и картинки, и видео, можно создать колонку `mediaType` (image|video|pdf)
   - можно также хранить картинку-источник. Т.е. если заказчик прислал Вам офигительно большие картинки, а Вы из них создали все нужные Вам размеры, то лучше сохранить имя источника. На тот случай, если вдруг понадобится новый размер - вы сможете перегенерировать все, имея ссылку.
   - можно хранить подпись под картинкой в отдельной колонке. "А вот это вид товара сверху"
   - в зависимости от типа товара Вам может понадобиться знать, какая картинка что изображает. Например, для одежды есть внешний вид, подкладка, материал (увелич.), рукав, воротничок, спина. Все это можно также оформить отдельной колонкой

Вобщем, как ответ, ОДНОЗНАЧНО: ***надо иметь отдельную таблицу***. И она дает неограниченные возможности сравнительно легкого хранения любых данных о картинке. От размеров и источника, до описания и статистики.

Answer (score 1):

Если товар предполагает более одного изображения, разумнее создать отдельную таблицу, причём хранить в ней достаточно имя изображения, а путь к изображениям исходным и превью генерировать с помощью php - имена превью и исходного изображений должны совпадать (для каждого товара создаём отдельную папку например по номеру id, в ней храним исходное изображение, в ней же создаём папку thm, где храним превью изображений)

```
/images/id/thm

id | good_ref_id | img |
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все коротко ясно!